# JavaFX access text fields from .fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, gluon

So I just wanted to try out JavaFX rather than using Swing for once (best decision of my life by the way), and I was just super confused on how I can access the text fields and add listeners to the buttons. I have made a .fxml file using Gluon SceneBuilder, and I was just wondering how I would access those elements in the fxml file.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: This may help: [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)

Comment: Slaw beat me to it. Specifically, look into the "Controllers" section. You have the FXML, now you'll need to add a controller to, well, control it. :)

Comment: Gotcha. I'll check this out! Thank you!